# MS SQL 2012 Trigger on Insert: Insert all rows from a table

Tags: sql-server

I am sorry if this question is too standard but I could not figure a way to do this   efficiently

I have 3 tables `Customer`, `CustomerProject`, and `StandardProject`

- `StandardProject` table contains a list of all projects that every customer in `Customer` table must have.

My logic is that when a new customer is inserted into `Customer` table, it will trigger and insert ALL projects from `StandardProject` into `CustomerProject`

```
Create Table [Customer]
(
   [CID] INTEGER PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1)
 , Customer   VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL UNIQUE 
)


Create Table [CustomerProject]
(
   ProjectID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1)
 , [CID]     INTEGER FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES [Customer](CID)
 , Project   VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL 
 , CONSTRAINT UN_Customer_Project UNIQUE([CID], Project)
)


Create Table [StandardProject]
(
    ProjectID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1)
 ,  Project   VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL UNIQUE
)

INSERT INTO [StandardProject](Project) VALUES('PROJECT 1')
INSERT INTO [StandardProject](Project) VALUES('PROJECT 2')
INSERT INTO [StandardProject](Project) VALUES('PROJECT 3')
```

Question: When I insert `Customer = 'My Customer'`, is there be a possible trigger that can add `'Project 1'`,  `'Project 2'`, `'Project 3'` into `CustomerProject` table?

In reality, the `StandardProject` can have a quite a few projects and these projects can changed frequency.

```
CREATE TRIGGER InsertStandardProjects ON [Customer]
FOR INSERT
AS

INSERT INTO [CustomerProject]([CID], [Project])...
```

Comment: Question: How do you know to which projects the incoming customer would be related?  That is, you're suggesting to auto populate the junction table as each new customer gets inserted.  But, which relationships would be inserted?

Comment: Hello @TimBiegeleisen, I do not need the relationship from `StandardProject` to the `CustomerProject` as long as it is unique to `Customer`.  `StandardProject` is like a dummy list.

Comment: Then maybe you don't even need the `CustomerProject` junction table in this case.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen but a customer can have other projects as well. Basically, a customer MUST have all dummy projects at the time it is created + other unique projects.  The issue is that my boss controls this dummy list and he changes it quite often.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, my logic can be messy but that all I came up with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this.

```
CREATE TRIGGER InsertStandardProjects ON [Customer]
FOR INSERT
AS
INSERT INTO [CustomerProject]([CID], [Project])
SELECT i.CID, St.Project
    FROM inserted i,StandardProject St
```

-- Check

```
INSERT INTO Customer (Customer) VALUES ('MyNewCustomer')

SELECT * FROM [Customer]
SELECT * FROM [CustomerProject]

Output:

CID Customer
1   MyNewCustomer

ProjectID   CID Project
1   1   PROJECT 1
2   1   PROJECT 2
3   1   PROJECT 3
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I suggest defining `CustomerProject` as:

```
CREATE TABLE [CustomerProject] (
    ProjectID INTEGER FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES [StandardProject](ProjectID),
    CID INTEGER FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES [Customer](CID),
    CONSTRAINT UN_Customer_Project UNIQUE(CID, ProjectID)
)
```

This junction table only exists to store relationships between customers and their projects, *not* the metadata associated with a customer or project.  So, storing the `Project` name here is not appropriate, and is just a waste of space.

That being said, you may try using the following trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER InsertStandardProjects ON [Customer]
FOR INSERT
AS

INSERT INTO [CustomerProject] (ProjectID, CID)
SELECT ProjectID, INSERTED.CID
FROM StandardProject

GO
```

The insert query in the above trigger makes use of `INSERTED`, which holds the values from the row being inserted, which includes the `CID` of the customer.